# How to break the chains of POOR CONDITIONAL FORMATTING options in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

use the following function to create an invoice.

```
=VSTACK(FILTER(PerformedTestsTable9,PerformedTestsTable9[Qty]>0,), {"","","Total sum to be paid:"})
```

Very simple, filtered table for Qty > 1 plus added row with VSTACK.

I use conditional formatting rules to format every other row, blank cells and the last row.

[image]

However every time I change something in the source table I get "Total sum to be paid:" left aligned in the bottom right cell. If I right align it manually it does not spill into adjacent left cell because it is not blank.
I can not add the borders I want, I can not change the font, I can not change the size of the font.

What I want is something like this:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve those results, even partially, without resorting to programming.
In pseudo-code

```
On Calculate
Turn off Manual Calculation
Unmerge cells that cause SPILL error in FILTER function
Reset formatting in the spill range of filter function to baseline
Calculate filter function
Identify bottom row and merge cells, right align merged cells, choose bigger font, add borders
```

Comment: Isn't it better manageable if you mention the `Total sum to be paid` in the second column instead? `{"","Total sum to be paid:",""}`

Comment: Absolutely. But that is not the point. I could come up with the solution for this one case, but the question is if there is an overarching solution to the scarcity of options in conditional formatting?

Comment: The things you need can't be done without the use of vba

Comment: Thanks. I kind of "sensed" that. Pretty poor act on Microsofts part.

Comment: VBA has all that and more